# How to programatically query for documents where property is null in ravendb

Tags: c#, ravendb

In ravendb studio I can do:

```
property: [[NULL_VALUE]]
```

How to do the same using `IDocumentQuery`?

The try below does not work.

```
documentSession
 .Advanced
 .DocumentQuery<Doc, Index>()
 .WhereIn("property", new[] {"[[NULL_VALUE]]", "some value"})
 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To query for `[[NULL_VALUE]]` or `[[EMPTY_VALUE]]`:

```
documentSession
 .Advanced
 .DocumentQuery<Doc, Index>()
 .WhereIn("property", new string[] {null, ""})
 .ToList();
```